# Laravel whereHas twice

Tags: php, laravel

I have some struggles with search method in controller. Functions must search in 2 tables, but it will search only in one, the first one. What could be proper approach here?

```
->when($search, function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->whereHas('info', static function (Builder $query) use ($search) {
                    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
                });
                $query->whereHas('merchant.translation', static function (Builder $query) use ($search) {
                    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
                });
        })
```

I tried with if statement if first one has null or undefined, but no success.Also I tried to separate when function.

Comment: Your second one should be an `orWhereHas()`.

Comment: Thanks <3######